# Why is slash so commonly used in old systems' abbreviations?

Tags: terminology

Many things around the '80s or earlier use ‘/’ in their abbreviations and sometimes even in their names, for example

- [IBM PS/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_PS/2), [OS/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS/2) and [PS/2 port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_port)
- [CP/M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP/M) - [MP/M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP/M) - [PL/M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/M) - [PL/I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/I) - [PL/S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_PL/S) - [PL/8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PL/8) along with [CP/NET, CP/NOS, MP/NET and MP/NOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP/M#CP/NET,_CP/NOS,_MP/NET_and_MP/NOS)
- [OS/8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS/8), [MS/8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS/8) and and PS/8
- [X/GEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GEM_(desktop_environment)#X/GEM)
- [z/Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z/Architecture), [System/360](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_System/360), [ESA/390](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_System/390#ESA/390_architecture)

Nowadays it's typically used to express *or* or *(sub)division* so I find it a little bit weird. Why was it used like that?

Comment: You forgot S/360 (1964), probably followed by PL/I (which you didn't forget).

Comment: @chthon: `S/360` seems to be a favorite pattern (general/specific) of IBM, they also had `S/34` and all their other names like `PS/2`, `OS/2`, `PL/I`. But, of course, they seemed to brreak that with `z/OS` for some reason.

Comment: Maybe the reason is nothing more than IBM, and others of the era, trying to catch the "halo effect" from the S/360 name.

Comment: [VAX/VMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVMS) Virtual Address eXtension/Virtual Memory System and [RSTS/E](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSTS/E) Resource Sharing Time Sharing Extended - Digital Equipment Company.

Comment: And "VAX-11/780" is less of a mouthful than "VAX-11 model 780".

Comment: I just wish to note one that is almost certainly an outlier: the "Apple //c." There it just seems that the / was used instead of an I for stylistic reasons. It's the Compact version of the Apple II computer.

Comment: If I look at a modern keyboard, I'd say that only three delimiters look sensible:  space, solidus, and hyphen, as in System 360, System/360, or System-360. Anything else has a sort of "trying too hard" look: System:360, System.360, System(360), etc.

Comment: And then on System/360 there was the programming language APL\360 ツ

Comment: @IconDaemon There was also RSX/11 from DEC. However they also had PDP-11, RT-11, etc.

Comment: @another-dave simply use System360 or PS2, it makes more sense

Comment: @user207421 - the systems were RSX-11M, etc.  Hyphen, not slash.  When DEC put a machine-related number on software, it was always offset with a hyphen:  FORTRAN-10, MACRO-11, BLISS-32.  It follows from the machine names: PDP-11, etc (with the obvious change fir VAX).  Model numbers used slash: PDP-11/45, etc.

Comment: I've always wanted to know how Spanish speakers pronounce OS/2.

Comment: @trlkly, Apple have a long history of strange naming, with their Apple `//`, `II`, `][` and so on :-)

Comment: Because 1) It's easier to type than a dash ("-") and 2) until the rise of URLs, slashes in names weren't a big problem for most people/things.

Comment: @RBarryYoung I'm going to use PS2, no need for anything like PS-2

Comment: @phuclv Sony would like a word with you.

Comment: Is that not broadly because "old systems" had access to many fewer options than ours do today, which made "slash" very much more useful than it would be today?

Comment: in `OS/2`, it's obvious it's a divider, "half an operating system"

Answer (score 35):

Well, at least on *some* of those, it's a quite natural divider, such as you would see in:

- 7 days/week (per).
- 13 sectors/track (per).
- Dear Sir/Madam (or).
- 3/7 (of/over).

For your cited examples, they are read as:

- **CP/M**, from Digital Research Inc (DRI), was the control program *for* microcomputers, though it *may* have originally been control program *and* monitor. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP/M) or, if you want it direct from Gary Kildall, his "Computer Connections: People, Places, and Events in the Evolution of the Personal Computer Industry" manuscript (available at the Computer History Museum) states:

  > So, I built an operting [sic] system program using the simulator. I called it CP/M, or a Control Program for Microcomputers, mimicking the name PL/M. For me, CP/M's sole purpose was to support the PL/M language. Nothing else.
- **MP/M**, multitasking program *for* microcomputers, though multi-programming monitor and control program for microcomputer systems development in [DRI's original specification](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/digitalResearch/mpm_I/MPM_1.0_Specification_Aug79.pdf).
- Several others were also from DRI and followed a similar nomenclature: **CP/NET** and **MP/NET** were similar to the preceding two but meant to operate over networks, hence control/multitasking program *for* networks.

  - Similarly, **CP/NOS** and **MP/NOS** were *for* network operating systems (diskless configurations).
- **PL/M**, programming language *for* microcomputers, foreshadowed above in the CP/M bullet point but more directly in the same document:

  > PL/M stands for a "Programming Language for Microcomputers," and is still used by Intel customers today, though largely supplanted by the "C" programming language.
- **PL/S**, programming language *for* systems. See references on [the Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_PL/S). Note that this was eventually replaced with PL/X, which is, at least up to several years ago when we parted ways, IBM's internal-use-only (I think) language for today's mainframe.
- **OS/8**, the OS *for* the PDP-8. **PS/8** I'd never heard of but it looks like (from cursory investigation) an early name for OS/8. The [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS/8) supports this as does the fact a later OS/12 was built for the, wait for it, ... , PDP-12 :-) An [unofficial history FAQ](http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/%7Ejones/pdp8/faqs/) also cites these, stating that OS/8 came from the unfortunately named (though probably intentional) "Fully Upward Compatible Keyboard Monitor", or *BLEEP* MONITOR :-)
- **MS/8** was also similar in that it was the monitor system *for* the PDP-8.

Contrast this "something something *for* something" approach with the (albeit fictional) **MCP** master control program from the original (and much better despite the much less modern graphics) *Tron* movie :-)

---

Some others, coming from IBM, have a similar format, seemingly dividing the general term from the specific instance:

- **PS/2**, personal system 2.
- **OS/2**, operating system 2, *not* half an operating system, as the early Windows crowd sometimes suggested :-)
- **PL/I**, programming language 1.
- **PL/8**, programming language 8 although it appears IBM usually referred to this as PS.8, humourously 80% of PL/I.

The PS/2 port, which is a type of connector into which mice and keyboards are plugged into, is so named because it was first introduced on the PS/2. It is a mini-DIN connector. Previously (and this is before USB prevalence), PCs generally used a larger (DIN) connector.

Comment: That's also the intended etymology for "GNU/Linux"... like the "over" in ½ (1 over 2). "GNU userland on/over the Linux kernel".

Comment: CP/M was originally `Control Program/Monitor` and even when reading `/` as *for* I still find it weird

Comment: _"despite the shoddy graphics"_ ? I must furiously disagree here. Thee graphics were a unbelievable, awe-inspiring perfect. The smooth surfaces of the tanks alone. Serious. I was STUNNED had to see it several times to believe these sequences were really computer made. Can' t really remember much of the (not really big) story, but I still can close my eyes and see the incredible graphics.

Comment: @phuclv / can be for, and, or and many other words, all depending on context, so in `Control Program/Monitor` it read `Control Program and Monitor`

Comment: I find the 1st half of this answer deeply unconvincing. You've started with "slash is a natural divider" and cited 2 examples where it's used as a stand-in for "per": "7 days per week", "13 sectors per track". And then listed a bunch of places where it's standing in for the word "for". I can't think of any modern places that I'd use slash as "for"?

Comment: @Raffzahn: I loved it as a kid and the *individual* graphic elements were good, like the tanks and bikes on the grid, though the "bit" was annoying to the level of Jar Jar Binks/Wesler Crusher :-) But the over-shimmering-blue-water lakes of energy was particularly bad. Keep in mind I'm comparing it to what we have now as well, which is probably not a fair comparison.

Comment: @Brondahl: you are aware that "per" means "for each", yes? That's why I used the phrase "natural divider" rather than "for". The former includes things like "Dear Sir/Madam" (sir or madam), and "3/7 (three of seven). I'll adjust the answer accordingly.

Comment: @paxdiablo No, comparison to later works is never fair. The same way as comparing classic games to modern ones isn't, even with 'pixel-art' games. They do not have to cope with limitations of back then, so their achievement isn't the same. And yes, I do in part agree about Bit. Then again, it was quite cool as well. keep in mind, even the term bit wasn't really common knowledge in 1982. (Then again, I have to admit I like Jar Jar Binks - he is essentially the only fresh (main) character in all of E1 - if not all of the new movies).

Comment: @paxdiablo If you're asserting that `CP/M` is representing `Control Program for each Microcomputer` then sure. But that doesn't seem likely. You've expanded your examples, but still not given *any* that map to "for" in the way you've then used it in your answer.

Comment: @paxdiablo another way to resolve this could be: can you give a citation for you suggested expansions? If those phrases are *known* to be what the 'acronym' stood for, then whether I agree with that usage of slash becomes entirely irrelevant.

Comment: @Brondahl: tracked down some citations and added, hopefully that will make the answer better. I'm not keen on adding *too* much more since, at some point, the size makes the answer (while more informative) a little unwieldy :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo fair enough; I'm sold :)

Comment: @paxdiablo It might be useful to order the examples by time, as that gives for some an easy to follow heritage. Like the inheritance of that stylization from PL/I being defined by IBM for and together with the S/360, to PL/M a simplified implementation of PL/I by Kildall for Intel to CP/M to Kidall's own CP/M and it's later derivatives.

Comment: Seems to me the "X for Y" phrasing is a sporting thing. In sports, "he's 3/3" is often pronounced "he's three for three."

Comment: Note on the "PS/2 Port" for mice and keyboards - the port name comes from the IBM PS/2 computer, where they were first introduced, so that's the same origin.  The fact that the ports long out-lived the computer they were first designed for is something of an accident of history.  (They're still seen on some modern desktops to this day, even though the peripherals they were made for have mostly all switched to USB.)

Comment: Thanks, @DarrelHoffman, I missed that one in the original list. Added to answer.

Comment: @ssokolow (1/2) That might be news to the GNU project. They have [their own explanation](https://www.gnu.org/gnu/linux-and-gnu.html): “Linux is normally used in combination with the GNU operating system: the whole system is basically GNU with Linux added, or GNU/Linux. … People could then [combine Linux with the GNU system](https://ftp.funet.fi/pub/linux/historical/kernel/old-versions/RELNOTES-0.01) to make a complete free system—a version of the GNU system which also contained Linux. The GNU/Linux system, in other words.”

Comment: (2/2) I am sure that I read specifically that “GNU” comes first because of its larger contribution, but I don’t have a citation now.

Comment: @BrianDrake Well, if you're going by largest contribution, then it'd be X11/GNU/systemd/Linux or possibly X11/systemd/GNU/Linux. Stallman put his finger on the scale by defining GCC and emacs as part of the OS and excluding a GUI, because, according to him, an OS is what you need to self-host its development and nothing more. Honestly, I'd like to see musl-libc and uutils become sufficiently drop-in compatible with GOG.com games that I can give the finger to people who whine about use of a name with too many syllables to ever catch on. We have enough trouble with "Ubuntu Linux, not Ubuntu".

Comment: ...unless you're talking about ABI... then it'd be glibc/Linux for the CLI apps or X11/glibc/Linux for the GUI ones... and, sure enough, applications like Firefox use something like `X11; Linux` as their platform identifier... typically, when it's compacted that far, on the basis that glibc is assumed to be the libc for Linux builds.

Comment: I'd never noticed before that `PL/I` uses roman numeral, rather than the usual digit 1.

Comment: IBM's publications always called it `PL.8` not `PL/8`. The `.8` is meant to be read as `80% of PL/I`. I think `PL/8` is officially wrong, albeit common. This was yet another of IBM's numerous secret dialects of PL/I, and all the others were named with a slash, so it is no wonder people named it with a slash too, even if that's wrong – those other secret dialects being the mainframe systems language `PL/S` (later renamed to `PL/AS` then `PL/X`), its IBM 8100 derivative `PL/DS`, and its AS/400 derivatives `PL/MP` and `PL/MI`

Comment: Is it possible that everyone else just copied it from CP/M?

Comment: @user253751: unlikely, PL/I has been around since the 50s, I think. CP/M only came out in the 70s.

Comment: @user253751 - rather than everyone copying it from CP/M, CP/M copied it from IBM. Before creating CP/M Gary Kildall worked at the Naval Postgraduate School, where he used an IBM mainframe operating system called CP/CMS – I think its name inspired that of CP/M (and likely also the idea of drive letters). Kidall wrote CP/M as an OS to go with his programming language PL/M, whose name was obviously inspired by IBM's PL/I programming language. CP/M is from 1974, PL/M from 1973, CP/CMS is from 1968, PL/I from 1964.

Answer (score 26):

In addition to Paxdiablo's [computing centred list](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/24168/6659) it might be worth to add that it's more of a linguistic issue than a technical or computing one.

The Slash was quite present way before data processing, back then known as *Solidus* or *Oblique*. Solidus, Latin for Shilling, as it grew out of the *[long-s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s)*, a letter, lost to modern Alphabets, used separate Shilling from Pounds. The long-s looks a bit like a stroke with a hook. The hook got lost over time due sloppy writing, transforming it into a straight slash. Solidus is in fact the name used within the Unicode classification for what we commonly call a slash.

Development and use case goes roughly:

- Slashes have been used as number separator long before Comma and Dot settled like today. This dates back to at least the 16th century.
- The usage is originated in the fact that in handwriting spaces can be rather random in width and appearance. Thus, separation is needed/helpful, some symbol gets inserted. Either a specific, or a generic like a slash.
- In fact, in many early Latin texts and many medieval handwriting spaces were optional or omitted at all. If a word separator was needed, like to switch for numerals, a middle dot was common.
- Slashes are still common in some countries (e.g. USA) as date separator (YY/MM/DD).
- It was and is used wherever one wants to concatenate items but still mark em as distinct. Like the *PL/I* example, were it serves to enable reading 'I' as one instead of the letter I.
- Similar the use with other product names like *System 360* abbreviated to *S/360*. This continues with *S/360-67* as abbreviation for the *System 360 Model 67*. Here a hyphen is used as secondary divider
- Usually these applications are about saving space, so the slash may as well serve as replacement for various words. They can stand for *and*, *or*, *for* or many others.
- This essentially works like the [title case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Title_case) used in English language publications. All words not capitalized are candidates to be left out at whole, or replaced by a slash. Like *Control Program for Microcomputers* becomes *CP/M*.
- In addition, much like there isn't *one* title case, but each publication fosters their own, people tend to make up their own variation  - for example it's common to write simply *360/67* instead of *S/360-67*.
- Speaking of, even companies change mid way, as there are as well IBM publications writing like that - or turning everything upside down by creating z/OS for something that started out as OS/360 :))
- Of course all of this is in addition garnished with heaps marketing related stylization, great for flashy advertisement and even better to play trademark games.
- The whole thing goes not only for products, but company names as well, or who remembers that *M/A/I* (sometimes *M|A|I*, today *MAI*) originally stand for *Management Assistance Incorporated*?

Long story short: Once it was about abbreviations, today everything goes, use it whenever pleases your intention.

---

Now, when looking at computing in particular, then there is a clear lineage, at least for some of the usage:

- IBM stylized **PL/I** to fit the scheme started with the together with the **S/360**
- Which in turn may have originated in use by US military bureaucracy like [Another-Dave pointed out](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/24176/6659).
- Intel's **PL/M** is a simplified implementation of PL/I, so it's name follows the precedence set.
- PL/M was written for Intel by Garry Kildall. When creating **CP/M**, not long after, the naming choice was obvious.
- Not much sleuth skills needed to see the continuation in **MP/M** and all that followed in DR's timeline of OSes.

Comment: Hmm, technically solidus isn't Latin for shilling, it means solid, in that the Roman coins were close to pure gold. The term shilling came much, much later as the name for the British coin, though its etymology stretches back to earlier times (but not so far as the Roman collapse, I suspect). It may be *more* accurate to say that the original shilling was English (proto-something-or-other, more likely) for solidus. This is the sort of obscure information you can gather by listening to "The History of English" podcast :-) That doesn't detract from an otherwise very informative answer, however.

Comment: The abbreviations for the old currency were £sd.  £ is a stylised L (which is often seen in 19C manuscripts) and stands for "libra pondo", a "pound by weight".  "s" as mentioned above was solidii which became "shillings" in English usage, and "d" is for denarii which became the penny.  As a footnote to £, recall that the abbreviation for pounds weight is "lb" and you can see the common origin.  The Norman £ was one lb of silver, specifically silver "starlings" (pence) from whence "Sterling".

Comment: @Martin Well,  to be fair, it was the Carolingian system introduced in the 8th century in Europe and soon after on the British Islands. Normans only came into play a century or two later.

Comment: Yes, but the terms "Lsd" and the £ symbol are a bit more recent, as are 19C manuscripts!  Some of us ancients still remember learning Lsd at school, and indeed using it.  My first pocket money was 1/-, rising later to 1/6.  When my Great Uncle visited he used to shake hands with us kids, and palm off half a crown which Mum pretended not to notice.  Homework for you: why was 13/4 a sum we had to memorise at school? ;-)

Comment: @Martin Well, wouldn't this be a Scottish Mark? Not only the English learned about LSD - I remember them being topic in 4th grade lecture in Bavaria in the 1960. Of course more of a curiosity to show kids that there are other (ancient) systems as well. Of course, being me, it cranked my imagination :)) Also, that Handshake might be universal to all Uncles all over the world. just the denomination might have been different :)) Regarding the 19C part, main point for having it mentioned above was the usage of a long-s - not a short one - at exactly that time.

Comment: @Martin - two-thirds of a pound (twice six-and-eight).

Comment: A customer from Australia kept explaining a command format that included an "oblique".  Inasmuch as I couldn't rotate characters 90 degrees (not in the '80's, anyway :) it took awhile to discover they were referring to the good old "slash".

Comment: @gbarry: I've had similar issues with people calling the octothorpe/hash (`#`) a "pound", presumably because `£` exists at shift-3 on UK keyboards. Or so I thought. As always, this led me down a rabbit hole regarding the *actual* source of the name which I won't go in to here since it's rather lengthy :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo It's not really about where the pound symbol is placed on the keyboard. It's that the pound glyph replaced the hash glyph in the UK's  version of 7 bit encoding, [ISO 646](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_646) - [IR-4 (BS 4730)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_1013). So any 'ASCII' value of X'23', producing a `#`  on a computer/terminal using ISO IR-6 (US-ASCII) will display a `£` on one using IR-6, which is what genuine UK computers do (Well, the BBC replaced Accent Grave instead to allow both in 7 bit encoding). Any `#` you've seen on your screen was a `£` on his.

Comment: @gbarry: Slash has two vulgar meaning in British (and I suspect Australian) usage, so there is a tendency to avoid it.  See https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/slash#Etymology_2

Comment: Just for interest: it's common practice in cave surveying still to use `/` in preference to `.` or `,` as decimal separator, as the former is much more likely to survive liberal quantities of mud and still be identifiable (or confidently absent).

Comment: Did MAI really have slashes as part of the company name, or just as a design feature in [the logo](http://www.obsoletecomputermuseum.org/mai/mai_0007.jpg)?  I worked for MAI Basic Four ~1980 and didn't know that.  Though, to be fair, I see that the name of the company I worked for was apparently "MAI Basic/Four" and I don't remember that slash (oops, I mean solidus) either.  So maybe my memory is shot.  (Sad.)

Answer (score 8):

This answer doesn't really answer the question of "why". But in any case....

In technical/computing fields, the solidus appeared in US military project designations.  A few examples:

[AN/FSQ-7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AN/FSQ-7_Combat_Direction_Central) - , vacuum tube computer, part of the SAGE air defense system.

[AN/FSQ-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AN/FSQ-32_) - solid state computer, also SAGE.

[AN/FSG-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_AN/FSG-1_Antiaircraft_Defense_System) - anti-aircraft defence system.

The structure of such names is that "AN" means "Army and Navy", "FSQ" is "Fixed Special eQuipment", and so on. The numeric part is a specific project.

It seems to me that the solidus is essentially an arbitrary choice of punctuation symbol to separate two logically distinct parts of the name, as is the hyphen before the numeric identifier.  There's no more to it than that.

Comment: I understand `/` in case of separation because I already mentioned (sub)division in the question, but it's not like that for CP/M or PS/2 or most of the names I listed above

Comment: I do not see the distinction that you do.

Comment: I also don't see the distinction. To me it seems like all are cases of "DOMAIN/SPECIFIC", rather than an abbreviation of the word "for".

Answer (score 4):

It is being used in the same way as you describe the modern usage- to express a subdivision of a whole.

In the case of your cited examples, the division is between the *Domain* and the *Specific* instance. Domains are things like "OS", "CP", "PL", etc. and the part after the "/" names the specific instance. So, you can best understand it as:

"In the Domain of Control Programs, here is the Microcomputer specific one- CP/M".

-OR-

"In the Domain of Operating Systems (for IBM PC's), here is specific revision number 2- OS/2".

It's rather simple and logical. The answer by another-dave makes this point as well, using examples that start with "In the Domain of Army and Navy gear..."

Comment: I'm not *necessarily* convinced about the 2 in OS/2 being a revision number or instance. Given that we had OS/2 1.3 (text only), 2.x, 3.x and 4.x/Warp(?), it seems *that* would be versioning information. OS/2 *may* have just been named as (originally) the operating system for the PS/2 (and the PS/2 may have been named as the (better) successor to the PC). Though, if you mean revision in a much *wider* scope, your answer makes more sense.

Comment: Domain/Specific is exactly what I said in the question `(sub)division`. It's nothing new but I'm not convinced that most of the names are in the domain/specific format

Comment: @paxdiablo OS/2 introduced a GUI in version 1.1 the text only version was 1.0 - the desktop was changed massively for 2.0 (From Wikipedia and my own experience programming 1.x)

Comment: @mmmmmm: I stand corrected, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: APL\1130 and APL\360 represented a bit of rebellion against the IBM culture that demanded this pattern.